# Date Difference between 3 dates

Tags: google-bigquery

I am calculating difference between 3 dates using legacy sql. 
The idea is to find difference in 2 days and when the second date is null should take the third date.

Have built the query below but the error is

```
SELECT
asset_tag , receive_date  , first_time , second_time , location , 
location_country ,
m_n12, display,
Datediff(  Case When second_time  is null Then first_time
When first_time  is null Then second_time
When first_time  > second_time  Then second_time
Else first_time
END as first_date ,receive_date )
FROM [abc_table]
where type in ('Laptop', 'Monitor', 'Desktop')
and receive_date >'2017'
```

Encountered " "AS" "as "" at line 8, column 9. Was expecting: ")"

Answer (score 1):

Remove the alias from the `CASE` expression:

```
DATEDIFF(CASE WHEN second_time IS NULL THEN first_time
              WHEN first_time IS NULL THEN second_time
              WHEN first_time > second_time THEN second_time
              ELSE first_time END, receive_date)
```

An alias might make sense on the entire function call to `DATEDIFF`, but it does not belong inside the function call itself.